# MySQL: Get percentage of change between two dates for multiple entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the percentage of change between two dates in my table. I have gotten the data together and into the following format, but am unable to move past towards getting the differences between the dates.

**Current Output:**

```
+------------+---------+--------+
|    day     | player  | score  |
+------------+---------+--------+
| 2016-12-20 | player1 |  69253 |
| 2016-12-15 | player1 |  61662 |
| 2016-12-15 | player2 | 309180 |
| 2016-12-20 | player2 | 318112 |
| 2016-12-15 | player3 |   1525 |
| 2016-12-20 | player3 |   1405 |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+---------------+
| Player  | startDate  |  endDate   | startScore | endScore | percentChange |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+---------------+
| player1 | 2016-12-15 | 2016-12-20 |      61662 |    69253 |        0.8904 |
| player2 | 2016-12-15 | 2016-12-20 |     309180 |   318112 |        0.9719 |
| player3 | 2016-12-15 | 2016-12-20 |       1525 |     1405 |       -0.0854 |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+---------------+
```

I am getting to this point with:

```
SET @maxDate = (SELECT DATE(from_unixtime(max(timestamp) /1000)) from city_data);
SET @minDate = date_sub(@maxDate, INTERVAL 5 day);

SELECT
    day,
    player,
    sum(score) as score
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(cd.timestamp / 1000)) as day,
        player,
        score
    FROM
        city_data cd
    WHERE
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(cd.timestamp / 1000)) IN(@minDate, @maxDate)
) t
GROUP BY
    day, player
```

What can I add to my query to get the desired output? I think we can assume the result of my query can be put into a temp table and used from there?

**Edit:** Per request an example of what the original table looks like (note this is just an example, the table is a few million rows)

```
---------------+--------------+-------+-----+
|   timestamp   |    player    | score |  id |
+---------------+--------------+-------+-----+
| 1477173600000 | player1      |    66 |   1 |
| 1477173600000 | player1      |   654 |   2 |
| 1477173600000 | player1      |     3 |     |
| 1477173600000 | player2      |   238 |   4 |
| 1477173600000 | player2      |  9123 |   5 |
| 1477287798758 | player1      |    69 |   6 |
| 1477287798758 | player1      |   678 |   7 |
| 1477287798758 | player1      |     8 |     |
| 1477287798758 | player2      |   698 |   9 |
| 1477287798758 | player2      | 11000 |  10 |
+---------------+--------------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: your percent change seems incorrect

Comment: It's an example output I did by hand, it might be off. Could you provide an example of the value that seems to be off? Though, regardless, I am sure a viewer can get the idea of what I am trying to achieve.
Edit: I see, I had the % backwards there.

Comment: can you show your original table?

Comment: @vkp Added a very short example

Comment: so do you want to get the difference of scores in a period of 5 days each for each player?

Comment: @vkp I'm taking the score from x days ago and comparing it to the current. Any scores in between do not matter. I'm comparing the score from 5 days ago to now to get the % of change for something like a leaderboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need the score comparison for every day and those 5 days previous to it, you can use a `self join`.

```
SELECT t1.player,
       t2.dt as startdate,
       t1.dt as enddate,           
       t2.score as startscore,
       t1.score as endscore,
       (t1.score-t2.score)/(1.0*t1.score) as pct_change
FROM (select player,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)) as dt,sum(score) as score from city_data group by player,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000))) t1
JOIN (select player,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)) as dt,sum(score) as score from city_data group by player,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000))) t2 
ON t1.player=t2.player AND DATE_SUB(t1.dt, INTERVAL 5 day) = t2.dt
```

If you need specific dates from this result-set, you can use a `where` clause to filter them. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT t1.player,
       t2.dt as startdate,
       t1.dt as enddate,           
       t2.score as startscore,
       t1.score as endscore,
       (t1.score-t2.score)/(1.0*t1.score) as pct_change
FROM (select player,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)) as dt,sum(score) as score from city_data group by player,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000))) t1
JOIN (select player,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)) as dt,sum(score) as score from city_data group by player,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000))) t2 
ON t1.player=t2.player AND DATE_SUB(t1.dt, INTERVAL 5 day) = t2.dt
) x
WHERE startdate = date '2016-12-15' and enddate = date '2016-12-20'
```

Explanation: Use a derived table to get the sum of scores of each player per day. Join it twice so that each day per player is joined with 5 days prior to it. After that refer to the tables and select the required values so they would be on the same row.

Comment: wow, that's great.
Could you provide an explanation for how the self-join works to provide these results? I'm having a hard to wrapping me head around it.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell .. check out the explanation and let me know.

Comment: Very good! I've prettified and optimized the query a bit now that I have puzzled out how it works. Got it from a  run-time of 8s to 2s. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
--Created test table
create table t (day date, player varchar(100), score integer);
insert into t values ('2016-12-20','player1',  69253);
insert into t values ('2016-12-15','player1',  61662);
insert into t values ('2016-12-15','player2', 309180);
insert into t values ('2016-12-20','player2', 318112);
insert into t values ('2016-12-15','player3',   1525);
insert into t values ('2016-12-20','player3',   1405);
```

And then

```
1. Find the `max` and `min` of day for each player -- table alias `t2`
2. Join it twice with original table
    1. First on player and min of day from t2 --> to get minimum score
    2. Then on player and max of day from t2 --> to get maximum score
3. then, do a group by to actually calculate min and max of score.
4. find percentChange at the end.

select t.*, (endScore-startScore) / endScore percentChange
from (
select t1.player, t2.startDate, t2.endDate, min(t1.score) startScore, max(t3.score) endScore
from t t1
inner join
(select player, min(day) startDate, max(day) endDate
from t
group by player) t2
on t1.player = t2.player
and t1.day = t2.startDate
inner join t t3
on t2.player = t3.player
and t3.day = t2.endDate
group by t1.player, t2.startDate, t2.endDate) t;
```

produces:

```
|  player |                  startDate |                    endDate | startScore | endScore | percentChange |
|---------|----------------------------|----------------------------|------------|----------|---------------|
| player1 | December, 15 2016 00:00:00 | December, 20 2016 00:00:00 |      61662 |    69253 |        0.1096 |
| player2 | December, 15 2016 00:00:00 | December, 20 2016 00:00:00 |     309180 |   318112 |        0.0281 |
| player3 | December, 15 2016 00:00:00 | December, 20 2016 00:00:00 |       1525 |     1405 |       -0.0854 |
```

Comment: That works great! However, could you add some explanations as to the process of the query. I am happy to get a solution, but I am more interested in understanding the queries flow.

Comment: @Douglas Added explanation